# How do I declare a global matrix in NETLOGO? (Using matrix extension)

Tags: matrix, declare, netlogo

I found an example using the following sintax:

```
let A matrix: from-row-list [[3 5] [0 1]]
let B matrix: from-row-list [[3 0] [5 1]]
```

But it keeps showing: Expected keyword. It selects the let reserved word. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`let` defines a variable that's local to a procedure or other embedded context, and it generates that error if used at the top level.  I guess that `let` doesn't count as a "keyword" in that context.

To define a global matrix, specify the variable name in `globals`, and then `set` it inside a procedure:

```
extensions [matrix]

globals [A B]

to setup
  set A matrix:from-row-list [[3 5] [0 1]]
  set B matrix:from-row-list [[3 0] [5 1]]
end
```

Then add a button that calls `setup`.  Note that you need to remove the space after "matrix:"